# Html form works fine on computer but submit button doesnt work on Mobile Phones

Tags: php, html, forms

Here's a simple html form code using php and POST method. It works fine on Computers but the submit button doesn't work on Mobile phones. It doesn't click when we touch it.

```
<form action="contact2.php" method="POST">
Your name:<br>
<input name="name" size="30" type="text" /><br> Your mobile no:<br>
<input name="phone" size="15" type="text" /><br> Your email:<br>
<input name="email" size="30" type="text" /><br> Your message:<br>
<textarea name="msg" rows="7" cols="30">
</textarea><br />
<input class="formsubmit"  type="submit" value="Send Email" />
</form>
```

Comment: maybe try <button> instead of <input> and restyle it with CSS.

Comment: Did that but doesnt work.

Comment: It is working in mobile devices. I have tested just now.

Comment: I think you have [`z-index`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYoNHfqvvTAhXJQY8KHbhADxsQFghjMA0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FCSS%2Fz-index&usg=AFQjCNE1nRQxt8Qu7R8h-1GR3KRI8QteIQ&sig2=IXLPIJeMR__mBLMWH19DQg) problem

Comment: Prasad, can you tell me how can i fix that?

Comment: Nimish, yes I've previously made html forms, all of em worked wonder why this one causing an issue

Comment: It's an old question, but the problem is related to css or other code so you must provide full code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use button tag instead of input

```html
<button class="formsubmit" type="submit">Send Email</button>
```